# SQL Query with a little bit more complicated WHERE clause performance issue

Tags: entity-framework, t-sql, database-performance

I have some performance issue in this case:

Very simplified query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Items WHERE ConditionA OR ConditionB OR ConditionC OR ...
```

Simply I have to determine how many Items the user has access through some complicated conditions.

When there is a large number of records (100,000+) in the Items table and say ~10 complicated conditions concatenated in WHERE clause, I get the result about 2 seconds in my case. The problem is when a very few conditions are met, f.e. when I get only 10 Items from 100,000.

**How can I improve the performace in this "Get my items" case?**

Additional information:

- the query is generated by EF 6.1
- MS SQL 2012 Express

[SQL Execution Plan](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/453274)

Answer (score 0):

Add an additional table to your schema. Instead of building a long query, insert the value for each condition into this new table, along with a key for that user/session. Then, JOIN the two tables together.

This should perform much better, because it will allow the database engine to make better use of indexes on your Items table.

Additionally, this will position you to eventually pre-define sets of permissions for your users, such that you don't need to insert them right at the moment you do the check. The permission sets will already be in the table, and the new table can also be indexed, which will improve performance further.

Comment: Ok I understand I can add one additional table with composite primary key of {ItemId, UserId} and the boolean value that represents the result of the whole WHERE clause concatenation for this combination of Item's and User's attributes. The price for this is the need for updates of this new table every time the Item's or the User's condition related attributes changes (or adding and removing the items itselves). Do I understand that correctly?

Comment: Partly. You should design your permissions system so that you're always making an equality comparison with the same column, and then you only need to store a single value in the new table.

Comment: "...making an equality comparison with the same column" means explicitly determine the user access for each Item. Right? But in my case I need to determine the user access also implicitly, meaning the right to access is determined using multiple linked tables (JOINS, EXISTS).